# Set cell value based on other cell's information

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want A1 to set the tier value of 0-4, based on B1's value (in hours).  For example, if B1 is "0", "1", or"2" (0-2), set A1 to 0, if B1 is "3" or "4", set A1 to 1, etc... Please help.

I have the following formula =IF(D2<3,"0",IF(D2>=3,"1",IF(D2<=4,"1",IF(D2>=5,"2"))))

But anything with the value of 5 or up, it keeps the value to "1"...

Thanks,
aB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formula becomes true at ...if(d2>=3,"1");

5 >= 3 so it returns 1.

try this
=IF(D2<3,"0",IF(D2>=5,"2","1"))

You may want to consider changing the first condition to D2<=2 so it exactly matches the description you gave.